# warning: control reaches end of non-void function (c++)

Tags: c++, controls, void

i get this error and can't fix, i'm noob yet,if someone can help me i'll thank you
this code come from xmplayer of libxenon (for jtag xbox)

(i try search similar error, but i can't find what's wrong)

```
  int FileSortCallback(const void *f1, const void *f2) {
    /* Special case for implicit directories */
    if (((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename[0] == '.' || ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename[0] == '.') {
        if (strcmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename, ".") == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (strcmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename, ".") == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename, "..") == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (strcmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename, "..") == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* If one is a file and one is a directory the directory is first. */
    if (((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->isdir && !(((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->isdir)) return -1;
    if (!(((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->isdir) && ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->isdir) return 1;

    //Ascending Name
    if (XMPlayerCfg.sort_order == 0) {
        return stricmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename, ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename);
    }
    //Descending Name
    else if (XMPlayerCfg.sort_order == 1) {
        return stricmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename, ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename);
    }
    //Date Ascending
    else if (XMPlayerCfg.sort_order == 2) {
        if ( ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->date == ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->date) { //if date is the same order by filename
            return stricmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename, ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename);
        } else {
            return ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->date - ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->date;
        }
    }
    //Date Descending
    else if (XMPlayerCfg.sort_order == 3) {
        if ( ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->date == ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->date) { //if date is the same order by filename
            return stricmp(((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->filename, ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->filename);
        } else {
            return ((BROWSERENTRY *) f2)->date - ((BROWSERENTRY *) f1)->date;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a sequence of `else if`s, but no `else`. The compiler might be getting hung up on that, even if you addressed every possible value.

Comment: `I am a noob.. ` here is for starters: A warning is not an error

Comment: @Aniket, It is when you use `-Werror`. I know it says warning in the title, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: Add return 0 at end of your function

Comment: thx people, i will try fix with some else

Comment: return 0 fix the problem thx all

Comment: Adding `return 0;` to the end of the function will silence the warning, but it fixes the problem only if `0` is actually the correct value to return if it reaches that point -- or if you can prove, by means not available to the compiler, that it will never reach that point.

Comment: The code would be much clearer if it defined a pair of local variables of type `BROWSERENTRY*`, initialized from `f1` and `f2` instead of casting everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler analyzes your code, and sees that a return statement will be executed for all values of `sort_order` between `0` and `5`, inclusive. However, if the `sort_order` is negative or more than `5`, the code would reach the end of the function without a return statement; that is why the compiler issues a warning.

Note that it may not be possible for `sort_order` to be set to a negative number or a number over `5` because of constraints in other parts of your code. However, the compiler does not know any of that, so it thinks that `sort_order` could have any value.

To fix this problem, add an unconditional return statement at the end.